# Using Retrofit How to handle this json response form?

Tags: android, retrofit

When i post(POST method) my id and password into my REST api, it retrured

```
{
  "key": "ef91707f0434a1a2a7581dd3f4f48d3bdad717"
}
```

I want save this `ef91707f0434a1a2a7581dd3f4f48d3bdad717` on my Sharedpreference.

**ReferSharedPreference.java (It's for easily using sharedpreference object)**

```
public class ReferSharedPreference {

    public final static String REF_LOGIN_KEY = "REF_LOGIN_KEY";

    static Context mContext;

    public ReferSharedPreference(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public void put(String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences pref = mContext.getSharedPreferences(REF_PREF_NAME,
                Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    public String getValue(String key, String dftValue) {
        SharedPreferences pref = mContext.getSharedPreferences(REF_PREF_NAME,
                Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        try {
            return pref.getString(key, dftValue);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return dftValue;
        }
    }
```

**LoginActivity.java**

```
        Call<ResponseBody> getkey = loginApiService.getkey(loginData);
        getkey.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                if(response.code() == 200) {
                    ReferSharedPreference ref_key = new ReferSharedPreference(getApplicationContext());
                    ref_key.put(ReferSharedPreference.REF_LOGIN_KEY, response.body().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.body().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ref_key.getValue(ReferSharedPreference.REF_LOGIN_KEY, "default").toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            }
```

In above codes (LoginActivity.java),

```
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.body().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ref_key.getValue(ReferSharedPreference.REF_LOGIN_KEY, "default").toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

Do not work. Even though my putty said `HTTP/1.1" 200 50`. I learned it means request is going well.

**Question** 
How can i save `ef91707f0434a1a2a7581dd3f4f48d3bdad717` on my sharedpreference?
Exactly i want save it like `Token ef91707f0434a1a2a7581dd3f4f48d3bdad717`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement method to save and load String value in `SharedPreferences` like this:

```
String key = "Token";
String value = "ef91707f0434a1a2a7581dd3f4f48d3bdad717";
//saving your key
sSavePreferences(getApplicationContext(), key, value);

//accessing your key
String mKey = sLoadSavedPreferencesString(getApplicationContext, key);
```

Method `sSavePreferences(Context context, String key, String value)` :

```
public static void sSavePreferences(Context context, String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

Method `String sLoadSavedPreferencesString(Context context, String key)`:

```
public static String sLoadSavedPreferencesString(Context context, String key) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

        String value = sharedPreferences.getString(key, "No Name Found");
        return value;
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
You can get that value as you got JSON Oject as response, like this

`String value;
        try {
            value = response.getString("key");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }`

---

**OR**

```
class MyKey {
        String key;
    }
...

Call<ResponseBody> getkey = loginApiService.getkey(loginData);
    getkey.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse (Call < ResponseBody > call, Response < ResponseBody > response){
            if (response.code() == 200) {
                ReferSharedPreference ref_key = new ReferSharedPreference(getApplicationContext());
                ref_key.put(ReferSharedPreference.REF_LOGIN_KEY, response.body().toString());

                String jsonString = response.body().toString();
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                Key result = gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyKey.class);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result.key, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ref_key.getValue(ReferSharedPreference.REF_LOGIN_KEY, "default").toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure (Call < ResponseBody > call, Throwable t){
        }

    }
```

In Above code GSON is used. GSON can be used to serialize and deserialize Java objects to (and from) JSON. Class MyKey is used which object is serialized and deserialized by GSON, by doing this your problem should solved

```
String jsonString = response.body().toString();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Key result = gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyKey.class);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result.key, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

Comment: Thank you Ngima Sherpa, but if `String value = "ef91707f0434a1a2a7581dd3f4f48d3bdad717";` is not fixed, i.e. String value = "123123"; or String value = "efwwewewe" depending on login id and password values could be changed. What I really want to ask you is how I can set this part: `String value = "ef91707f0434a1a2a7581dd3f4f48d3bdad717";`.

Comment: from where the value is coming ?
you can assign value to `value` like `String value = getValueAccordingToLogInIdAndPassword();` 
but you have to implement  `String getValueAccordingToLogInIdAndPassword(){}` method by yourself.

Comment: um.. i mean the value is coming from server rest api. it's form is `{
  "key": "ef91707f0434a1a2a7581dd3f4f48d3bdad717"
}` . First i POST my json on HTTP body such as `{"id":"id_is_this", "password":"password_is_it"}`, and then response is such as `{
  "key": "ef91707f0434a1a2a7581dd3f4f48d3bdad717"
}`. I want this response. Sorry for bothering you

Comment: sorry, yes, your right, I was too busy to check your comment. it's json object right.

Comment: Sorry, I can't check your kind comment immediately, but i have a question. Where i should put your **UPDATE**? In onResponse?, because i'm new in programming acctually.. I can't know exactly where i put your nice codes in my project. I almost know your codes are very nice, but i can't use it right way. sorry, Would you let me know?

Comment: Is it okay i'll try your codes and may i ask you something after hours?

Comment: You can Use GSON as in Update :)

Comment: With a class MyKey

Comment: Sorry, Ngima. your answer was very good, but it returned `FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.keepair.myapplication, PID: 25964                                              com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 ` AND `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $`  at  **`MyKey result = gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyKey.class);`** I'm very Sorry for bothering you. I made MyKey class and getter and setter, but it gave me that as i said above.

Comment: Cause of your nice answer, I've made this solved! Very Thank you. Nigma Sherpa.